# Powershell Module MicrosoftTeams release 2.5.0 EDU templates not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a team in an EDU tenant using the `-Template "EDU_Class"` argument with the just released version 2.5.0 of the microsoftteams module.

`new-team -displayname "Test team" -template "EDU_Class"`

It fails with:

```
new-team : Error occurred while executing 
Code: BadRequest
Message: Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest.
```

2 items of note:

1. The template "EDU_PLC" works successfully which validates that I'm an EDU tenant.
2. This works properly with version 1.1.6 of the microsoftteams module.

Anyone else in an EDU Tenant able to create EDU_Class template base teams in version 2.5.0?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolve in the next release version 2.5.1 of the microsoftteams module

Comment: While this does not directly address the question, which specifies version 2.5.1, I do believe it will be of use to future answer seekers; so they know they only need to upgrade.